# determine if div class exists?

Tags: c#, .net

in c#.net using htmlagilitypack, how would I determine if "test3" exists/is there?

i am accessing each article using a foreach loop with a HTMLNode defintion for each element that exists.

I tried

if (node.descendants("div") == true)... but this wouldn't work

Comment: be sure to mark the answer that helped you the most as correct on your past questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath.

```
bool exist = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='test3']") != null;
```

It would be much simpler than linq version

```
bool exist = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                .Any(div => div.Attributes["class"] != null && 
                            div.Attributes["class"].Value == "test3");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (node.Descendants("div").Any(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("test3")))
{

}
```

`class` can (and often does) contain more than one item, separated by spaces.   It may be better to see if it `Contains` test3